# How to convert \\xhh into \xhh python

Tags: python, string, hex

I have encounter a case where I need to convert a string of character into a character string in python.

```
s = "\\x80\\x78\\x07\\x00\\x75\\xb3"
print s #gives: \x80\x78\x07\x00\x75\xb3
```

what I want is that, given the string s, I can get the real character store in s. which in this case is "\x80, \x78, \x07, \x00, \x75, and \xb3"(something like this)�xu�.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`string-escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) (Python 2.x):

```
>>> s = "\\x80\\x78\\x07\\x00\\x75\\xb3"
>>> s.decode('string-escape')
'\x80x\x07\x00u\xb3'
```

Use [`unicode-escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) (in Python 3.x, need to convert to bytes first):

```
>>> s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'\x80x\x07\x00u³'
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can build a string from the byte values, but that might not all be "printable" depending on your encoding, example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = "\\x80\\x78\\x07\\x00\\x75\\xb3"
r = ''
for byte in s.split('\\x'):
    if byte:  # to get rid of empties
        r += chr(int(byte,16))  # convert to int from hex string first

print (r)  # given the example, not all bytes are printable char's in utf-8
```

HTH, Edwin

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write a function, taking the string and returning the converted form!

something like this:

```
def str_to_chr(s):

    res = ""
    s = s.split("\\")[1:]  #"\\x33\\x45" -> ["x33","x45"]
    for(i in s):
         res += chr(int('0'+i, 16)) # converting to decimal then taking the chr  
    return res
```

remember to print the return of the function.

to find out what does each line do, run that line, if still have questions comment it... i'll answer